# Can I know the users who enter to my site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We recently set up an intranet in sharepoint online and We constantly check the trends in the site. But is it possible to go a little further and know the name of the users who visit the site in a given day?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Audit Report given by SharePoint to get Reports of changes made by users. Please follow below link for more information.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-f5a346d0-ee0f-4412-a5e6-d9b5abaa1012

OR

Go for Customization like Timer Jobs, Workflows,Scripts etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You create a list to store all users which have visited your site. Then you could use Javascript to get the current user, as described in this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73064/get-the-login-name-of-the-current-user-using-javascript). Then, you could check if the user has visited the site today. If he/she has not visited the site, then add that user to the list.

If you have a very large number of visitors, then maybe you could store the data
on the database, and build a web API to be called by your javascript code.